# UI Test tap() not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I have a splash screen that shows for 3 seconds and then fades in to a new view. On this view, there is a `UILabel` called "Privacy Policy" that I have attached a `UIGestureRecognizer` to. I'm trying to use UI tests to tap on that label to trigger a navigation controller push. This works in real life, however, during UI testing the tap doesn't do anything. My code looks like this:

```
func testPrivacyPolicyLink() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")
    expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: app.images["Logo"], handler: nil)

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5) { error in
        XCTAssertNil(error, "Splash screen took too long")
        sleep(4) // Added this just to make sure the splash screen has fully faded away
        app.staticTexts["Privacy Policy"].tap() // Should trigger a navigation controller push, but doesn't do anything
    }
}
```

Even when recording a UI test for this situation, it calls `app.staticTexts["Privacy Policy"].tap()` which works. But when I play it back, it doesn't work. Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: why not just make it a button?

Comment: @LukePatterson It's complicated... But that shouldn't matter?

Comment: Is the "Logo" the logo on the splash screen? If so, I think you may have an error in your logic. When you run the test with a breakpoint on the line with the tap, does the breakpoint get hit?

Comment: @user2277872 The whole point of this test is that should I accidentally break the code on that label, my tests will tell me.

Comment: @Oletha No it's not, the expectation is fulfilled, it just hangs for 60s on the tap and then says it "failed to quiesce" and quits

Comment: That's happened to me before, I've searched for a repeatable solution but it eventually goes away. Reset the simulator, restart Xcode, clean the project, delete derived data etc...

Comment: Did You find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You need to setup accessibility traits for this view to be "Button" or "Link" so it would be clear to the accessibility system that this elements are touchable. You can set it in the Interface Builder, select Identity inspector in the Utilities pane and set Accessibility Identifier and traits classes
[image: Identity inspector screenshot]

alternatively you can do this in code

```
self.view.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton;
self.view.accessibilityIdentifier = "departments selection";
```